# Trouble with D3.js CSV data and accessor functions

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So I have a very simple CSV file of 5 columns and 9 rows and am playing around with some newbie D3 code in the browser, serving my files using the SimpleHTTPServer module that comes with Python, and working in Chrome 48.0.

The following DOES work:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

This causes the console to return an array of objects, where each object represents one of the rows in my CSV file. So that's good. The returned `data` looks like this:

```
data = [
    {country: "USA", label: "San Francisco", population: "750000"},
    {country: "USA", label: "Fresno", population: "500000"},
    ...
];
```

The following DOES NOT work:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(data) {
    d3.min(data, function(el) {
        return +el.population
    });
});
```

Here, I expect `d3.min()` to go through every object in the `data` array, each of which is represented by the `el` argument, look at its "population" property, and return the minimum value out of all the objects in the array -- a single integer.

Instead, the Chrome console returns some weird nonsense that I don't understand that looks like this:

Object {}
abort: ()
get: ()
header: (n,t)
mimeType: (n)
on: ()
post: ()
response: (n)
responseType: (n)
row: (n)
send: (e,r,u)
**proto**: Object

Basically it looks like the `data` argument is not successfully passed to the `d3.min()` method. Which is weird because clearly, in the simpler first example, my CSV file does load correctly and the `data` argument is correctly carried through to the line `console.log(data)`.

I'm really stumped as a D3 novice. Am I misunderstanding something really basic here about how to load in data and work with it?

Thanks!

Comment: There is something strange in your code  i did exactly what you did and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/mbkvw68e/ can you make a fiddle to recreate your issue..

Comment: The full exact code I used is in the block under "The following DOES NOT work". Meaning, I didn't first define an array called "data", as you did in your JSFiddle. If I do it your way, it works for me too. Rather, I imported an external CSV file using d3.csv(), as shown, then passed that to d3.min() as the argument "data". I showed the array of "data" in my question to illustrate its structure, which I can successfully log to the console using the code under "The following DOES work". I can't seem to make a Fiddle b/c it involves loading an external file, which is where the problem begins.

Comment: yes! you can make a fiddle with external resources, you can keep CSV in https://gist.github.com/ and load it into your jsfiddle.